# Unable to trace type-expectation error in Rust

Tags: rust, sdl-2, rust-crates

**Repository**
https://github.com/hunterlester/rusty_arcade

**Versions**
Rust: 1.7.0
sdl2: 0.16.1
sdl2_image: 0.16.0

**Error**

```
src/views/mod.rs:88:13: 93:23 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::option::Option<sdl2::rect::Rect>`,
    found `sdl2::rect::Rect`
(expected enum `core::option::Option`,
    found struct `sdl2::rect::Rect`) [E0308]
src/views/mod.rs:88             Rectangle {
src/views/mod.rs:89                 x: 0.0,
src/views/mod.rs:90                 y: 0.0,
src/views/mod.rs:91                 w: self.player.rect.w,
src/views/mod.rs:92                 h: self.player.rect.h,
src/views/mod.rs:93             }.to_sdl(),
src/views/mod.rs:88:13: 93:23 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see  a detailed explanation
src/views/mod.rs:94:13: 94:38 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::option::Option<sdl2::rect::Rect>`,
    found `sdl2::rect::Rect`
(expected enum `core::option::Option`,
    found struct `sdl2::rect::Rect`) [E0308]
src/views/mod.rs:94             self.player.rect.to_sdl()
```

**Tracking it down**
Lines 93 and 94 of the specified file.

```
phi.renderer.copy(&mut self.player.tex,
            Rectangle {
                x: 0.0,
                y: 0.0,
                w: self.player.rect.w,
                h: self.player.rect.h,
            }.to_sdl(), // Line 93
            self.player.rect.to_sdl() // Line 94
        );
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with what the `.to_sdl()` method is returning.

**to_sdl method**

```
impl Rectangle {
    pub fn to_sdl(self) -> SdlRect {
        assert!(self.w >= 0.0 && self.h >= 0.0);

        SdlRect::new(self.x as i32, self.y as i32, self.w as u32,  self.h as u32)
    }
```

to_sdl returns an SdlRect which is in use at top of file:

```
use sdl2::rect::Rect as SdlRect;
```

**sdl2 source**
https://github.com/AngryLawyer/rust-sdl2/blob/master/src/sdl2/rect.rs

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Rect {
    raw: ll::SDL_Rect,
}

impl Rect {

pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32, width: u32, height: u32) -> Rect {
    let raw = ll::SDL_Rect {
        x: clamp_position(x),
        y: clamp_position(y),
        w: clamp_size(width) as i32,
        h: clamp_size(height) as i32,
    };
    Rect { raw: raw }
}
```

I don't see where `sdl2::rect::Rect` is expected to be wrapped in a `core::option::Option` enum type.

If you happen to be familiar with the tutorial that I'm following, you'll notice that I'm using a different version of `sdl2_image` than specified in the tutorial because the specified has been yanked from Crates.

`sdl2_image` depends on a different version of `sdl2` which I had to match in order to take care of other errors.

Comment: please copy the error as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means that the expression `self.player.rect.to_sdl()` yields a `SdlRect`, but that whatever uses that value, expects to be given an `Option<SdlRect>`. You are calling the [`copy`](http://angrylawyer.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2/render/struct.Renderer.html#method.copy) of `sdl2::render::Renderer`, which has the following arguments:

```
&mut self, texture: &Texture, src: Option<Rect>, dst: Option<Rect>
```

As you can see, you need to pass two `Option<Rect>`s. The sdl-crate's documentation even says why:

> Copies a portion of the texture to the current rendering target.
>
> - If `src` is `None`, the entire texture is copied.
> - If `dst` is `None`, the texture will be stretched to fill the given rectangle.